# NavigationComponent with BottomNavigationView item selection

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using NavigationComponent with BottomNavigationView.

When i using navigation like that (A->B->B1) bottom navigation automatically change his selected item from A to B.
I'm using default method for navigation.

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_A_to_B)
```

Then in fragment B i use again

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_B_to_B1)
```

Only in this way I get the desired result.

When i tried to use navigation like that (A->B1) my bottom navigation don't change his selection from A to B.

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_A_to_B1)
```

[image: Schema of behaviour]

Comment: When you programmatically navigate to an item, you have to let the bar know by setting its `selectedItemId`. `bar.selectedItemId = <the id of your selected menu item>`

Comment: @MartinMarconcini My Activity holds BottomNavigationView. I do navigation from Fragment.

Comment: Then delegate the responsibility to update the bar to the corresponding entity (your activity). Why would your fragment attempt to mutate the activity if it doesn't own it?

Comment: @MartinMarconcini I've done this because my buttons for navigation inside my fragments. Should i create public method for navigation inside activity then invoke him?

Comment: I don't get it, who inflates and sets the Bar? In any case, you should read [how to communicate between activities and fragments](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html) documentation (or, if you're more adventurous, use the newer ideas: a shared [ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

Comment: If you are unsure, create a new Android Studio project, and use `Bottom Navigation Activity` template (it's a little bit outdated) but it will give you an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When navigating, you can change the selection programmatically by this statement:

```
bottomNavigation.selectedItemId=R.id.itemFragmentB
```